# How do IMEI trackers work online

Tags: cellular

This may be the wrong site to ask this, but I am curious.

I've been doing some research and I know you can pull IMEI if you sniff cell phone signals by towers, but there are a bunch of websites that allow you to search and lookup IMEI numbers. How are such websites able to pull information without having some type of connection to towers or the cellular provider's internal network?

Comment: "This may be the wrong site to ask this" - You are right;  It is the wrong Stackexchange website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrong StackExchange, but the answer is pretty easy. All phones have carrier and device information attached to them. With POTS, this is usually accessed via the phone number. Because cellular devices can change numbers, this is tracked via a globally unique identifier, the IMEI (also MEID). Here are some resources for further info:

https://www.maketecheasier.com/imei-number/

http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/phones-imei-makeuseof-explains/